# For every integer $a$ and $b$, does there exist a $c$ such that $a\mid c^2-b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Is this proof correct?

Using adversary argument, if the adversary chooses any $a$ and $b$ to be $a+1$, since
$$c^2 = aq+b = aq + (a+1)$$
then $\gcd(a,a+1) = 1$ therefore, $\gcd(c^2,a) = 1$ so for every $a$ and $b$ there isn't a $c$ such that $a\mid c^2-b$.

Comment: "therefore $\gcd(c^2, a) = 1$" and what's wrong with that? " for every a and b there isn't a c such that a∣c2−b" well obviously there are *some* $7|5^2 - 4$ for example.  Back to your answer $a = 3$ $b = 4$ we have $5^2 = 3*7 + 4$ and therefore $\gcd(5^2, 3) = 1$ which is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument doesn't prove the statement: if one chooses $b=a+1$, then you do correctly show that any $c$ for which $a\mid c^2-b$ must have the property that $\gcd(c^2,a)=1$, but you don't argue anywhere that $c$ cannot exist.

However, you can argue by counterexample: if $a=3$ and $b=2$, then there is no integer $c$ such that $3\mid c^2-2$.

In general, there is such a $c$ if and only if $b$ is a **quadratic residue** modulo $a$ ([see more on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $a = 1$, your counter-example doesn't work. Try taking $a = 3$ and $b = 2$ and you will find that no $c$ satisfies $a \mid c^2 - b$. Welcome to the wonderful world of [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).